# child action doesn't trigger parent jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have couple `<a>` within a parent div which will perform a specific action when clicked. How can I make it so that when user clicks each `<a href="xxxx">`, user will only get linked to other pages and the parent function will not be triggered?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the `click` event from bubbling up to the parent, like so:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/EfQyY/)

Comment: @Henry - make sure you're attaching it on `$(document).ready`