# Prevent click event from affecting parent jquery

Tags: jquery, events, propagation, stoppropagation

I was to stop the event propagation from the child to the parent, i have a bunch of `li` tags containing `a`.

```
$('li a[rel=close]').live('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

But it doesn;t stop the event.Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does the event fire at least? Can you share your HTML code too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [child action doesn't trigger parent jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975946/child-action-doesnt-trigger-parent-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stopPropagation` has problems with `live`, from the jQuery [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) docs -

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events

As Rob W has said your code would work fine with `bind`, here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/TmKyT/

Comment: ``stopPropagation`` works for stopping the bubble from triggering ancestor **live** events, but it will trigger other listeners in the bubble that where bound using **bind** http://jsfiddle.net/yEnzC/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.bind` instead of `.live`. The `live` event is triggered at the end of the propagation tree. `live` is only more useful than `bind` when you want to also bind the event listener for elements which are created later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using delegate?

```
$('ul.parent').delegate('li a[rel=close]', 'click', function( event ) {

}
```