# jquery click on a child ignore parent click

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent click event from affecting parent jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696098/prevent-click-event-from-affecting-parent-jquery)

I have a DOM structure similar to this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">

   </div>
</div>
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('.parent').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

When `.child` is clicked I don't want the parent to hide but obviously because `.child` is a child of `.parent` this naturally happens. I've tried adding this:

```
$('.child').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But it still doesn't work. I've also tried replacing `e.stopPropagation` with `return false;`

any suggestions?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPUTe/)

Comment: I tried searching, but none of the solutions worked. I'm going to put my code into jsfiddle so you can see for yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This definitely works see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzxSM/) of your code. Try clicking the green div. If it does not work on your site, you have another issue.

Comment: hmmmm, any idea why it doesn't work in my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/mPUTe/

Comment: Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPUTe/2/). Your problem was that you are binding the click event, when the element did not yet exist. Alternatively you could use a live event

Answer (score 2):

Ah well, here's the solution: **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mPUTe/1/**.
Don't bind an event listener to the `.pu_container`. Instead, check whether `e.target` at the `.pu_bg` click listener has class `pu_container`. If yes, return.

```
 (function($) {
    $.fn.show = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var link = $(this);
            link.click(function(e) {
                $('body').append('<div class="pu_bg">');
                $('.pu_bg').css({
                    'opacity': 0.5
                }).on('click', function(e) {
                    if($(e.target).hasClass('pu_container')) return; //<--Magic?
                    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                        $(this).remove();    
                    });
                });;
                $('.pu_bg').append('<div class="pu_container">');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```